# Convert yaml to property file in helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

I would like to convert a part of the structure in values.yaml to properties file in a config map.

Is it possible to convert a yaml structure like:

```
field1: value1
field2:
   field21: value21
   field22: value22
```

into

```
field1=value1
field2.field21=value21
field2.field22=value22
```

with Helm templating functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a programming problem, this is a straightforward recursive call.  You can use Go `text/template` templates like functions.  The one trick here is that they only take a single parameter, so you need to use the [sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html) `list` function to pack multiple values into that parameter, and the [`text/template`](https://godoc.org/text/template) `index` function to get values back out.

```
{{- define "envify" -}}
{{- $prefix := index . 0 -}}
{{- $value := index . 1 -}}
{{- if kindIs "map" $value -}}
  {{- range $k, $v := $value -}}
    {{- template "envify" (list (printf "%s.%s" $prefix $k) $v) -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- else -}}
{{ $prefix }}={{ $value }}
{{ end -}}

data:
{{ template "envify" (list "" .Values.fields) | indent 2 }}
```

This will work with arbitrarily deep nested values.

If you refer to standard Helm variables (`.Release`, `.Values`, ...) this also becomes tricky because the `.` variable is reused for the single template parameter (it also gets reused within the `range` loop).  I tend to explicitly pass it as an additional template parameter.

```
{{- $top := index . 2 -}}
# from the {{ $top.Chart.Name }} Helm chart

{{/* in your ConfigMap proper */}}
{{ template "envify" (list "" .Values.fields .) }}
```

Comment: This as is was causing the the key to be prefixed with a dot. Changing `{{- $prefix := index . 0 -}}` to `{{- $prefix := trimPrefix "." (index . 0) -}}` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to bring your values under separate key and some [Sprig Template Functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) in your `Configmap`.

**values.yaml**

```
fields:
  field1: value1
  field2:
    field21: value21
    field22: value22
```

**configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: Configmap
data:
{{ range $key, $value := .Values.fields }}
  {{- if kindIs "map" $value -}}
  {{ $top:=$key }}
  {{- range $key, $value := $value }}
  {{ $top }}.{{ $key }}={{ $value }}
  {{- end -}}
  {{- else -}}
  {{ $key | indent 2}}={{ $value }}
  {{- end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

**helm template . -x templates/configmap.yaml**

```
---
# Source: mychart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: Configmap
data:
  field1=value1
  field2.field21=value21
  field2.field22=value22
```

I suggest extracting this logic to **_helpers.tpl** file. You will need to add more logic if you have more nested configs.

Answer (score 3):

The answers here weren't quite enough for me, so I took them as a baseline and improved them until I had something that worked.

I still wanted the recursive reading of any properties under some sort of key in my values.yaml, but I wanted it to be formatted for use with dotenv.

Here's what I came up with:

values.yaml

```
config:
  database:
    name: my-db
    host: my-db-host
    port: 5432
```

ConfigMap

```
data:
  .env: |-
    {{- include "envify" (list "" .Values.config . ) | nindent 4 }}
```

Template:

```
{{- define "envify" -}}
{{- $prefix := index . 0 -}}
{{- $value := index . 1 -}}
{{- if kindIs "map" $value -}}
  {{- range $k, $v := $value -}}
    {{- if $prefix -}}
        {{- template "envify" (list (printf "%s_%s" $prefix $k | upper) $v) -}}
    {{- else -}}
        {{- template "envify" (list (printf "%s" $k) $v) -}}
    {{- end -}}
  {{- end -}}
{{- else -}}
{{ $prefix }}={{ $value }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Output:

```
data:
  .env: |-
    DATABASE_NAME=my-db
    DATABASE_HOST=my-db-host
    DATABASE_PORT=5432
```

Hopefully this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

The recursive call to the same template is straightforward.
The below snippet is working. It should convert values.yaml to configmap data as property.

```
{{- define "envify" -}}
{{- $prefix := index . 0 -}}
{{- $value := index . 1 -}}
{{- if kindIs "map" $value -}}
  {{- range $k, $v := $value -}}
    {{- if $prefix -}}
        {{- template "envify" (list (printf "%s.%s" $prefix $k) $v) -}}
    {{- else -}}
        {{- template "envify" (list (printf "%s" $k) $v) -}}
    {{- end -}}          
  {{- end -}}
{{- else -}}
{{ $prefix | indent 2 }}={{ $value }}
{{ end -}}
{{- end -}}
```